# What am I doing wrong in this inequality?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Q. The solution set of the inequality
$$||x|-1|<|1-x|, x \in R$$

My Solution:
Case1: If $x≥0$

$||x|-1|<|1-x|$
=> $|x-1|<|1-x|$
Hence, S1=>$ x \in ∅ $

Case2: If $x<0$
$||x|-1|<|1-x|$
=> $|-x-1|<|1-x|$
=> $|x+1|>|x-1|$
=> $|x+1|-|x-1|>0$

Critical Points are -1 and 1

Subcase1: If $X<-1$
$|x+1|-|x-1|>0$
=>$-(x+1)-[-(x-1)]>0$
=>$-2>0$ 
Hence SubSolution1=> $x \in ∅$

Subcase2: If $-1<x<1$<br
$|x+1|-|x-1|>0$
=>$x+1-[-(x+1)]>0$
=> $x>0$
Hence SubSolution2=> $x \in (0,1)$

Subcase3: If $x>1$
$|x+1|-|x-1|>0$
=>$x+1-(x-1)>0$
=>$2>0$
Hence SubSolution3=> $x \in (1, \infty)$
Hence Solution2=> $Subsolution1 \cup SubSolution2 \cup Subsolution3 $
=> $∅ \cup (0,1) \cup (1, \infty)$
=>$(0, \infty)$

Final solution=> $ S1 \cup S2$
=> $∅ \cup (0, \infty)$
=> $(0,\infty)$

But the actual answer is $(-\infty, 0)$

Comment: Well, to begin with: In case 2, where you're assuming $x<0$, your subcases shouldn't contain any nonnegative values of $x$. So Subcase 3 should never have been considered, for example. (That's not the only error, though...)

Comment: I think one error is when you pass from the second to the third line in Case 2. You are not actually multiplying by $-1$ since $|-1-x| = |1+x|$

Comment: use $|1-x|=|x-1|$ and probably find your mistake. Or just plug in some positiv number for x to see that you are wrong

Comment: Why not just square the inequality? We get $$0<(|x|-1)^2<(1-x)^2\iff |x|>x,$$ that is $x<0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case 2 your implication $\vert -x -1 \vert   \lt \vert 1-x\vert $ implies $\vert x +1 \vert   \gt \vert 1-x\vert $ is wrong as

$$\vert -x -1 \vert  =\vert x+1 \vert \lt \vert 1-x\vert $$

Comment: Thanks to all, but can you please explain how $|-x-1|=|x+1|$ ?

Comment: @swarnim In general, $\lvert -y \rvert = \lvert y\rvert.$ Try $y = x + 1.$

Comment: @swarnim look back at the definition of $|x|$

Comment: Ohh, now I get it. $|-x-1|=|-(x+1)|$. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here it is another way to approach it for the sake of curiosity.

Since both sides are nonnegative, we can square them so that we obtain an equivalent inequation:

\begin{align*}
||x| - 1| < |1 - x| & \Longleftrightarrow (|x| - 1)^{2} < (1 - x)^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x^{2} - 2|x| + 1 < 1 - 2x + x^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow |x| > x
\end{align*}

which is true iff $x\in(-\infty,0)$, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is in the spirit of the question but we can also solve the inequality by plotting or just visualising the graph of $|1-x|=|x-1|$ and $||x|-1|$.

First you can plot $|x-1|$ which is $|x|$ curve shifted one unit right. Now, in the other curve $x$ is replaced by $|x|$ in $|x-1|$ which makes its graph different for only negative $x$ where the curve $||x|-1|$ is reflection of $|x-1|$ about $y-axis$.

Now it can easily noticed that the inequality is satisfied for all $x<0$.

Comment: Yes I have also seen such methods but can you show me a tutorial which show how to make such graphs.(I know how to make the graph of inequalities in 2 variables)

Comment: @swarnim A tutorial? At this platform. I don't know how can that be achieved, if you want to know how or why these graphical transformations work you can read any elementary level calculus book. I'm adding one reference here. http://facultymembers.sbu.ac.ir/shahrokhi/stewart.pdf You can read from page 36.